# using Base64 images in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, base64

I am trying to use Base64 encoded images in my react app.

currently I load images from a folder and looks something like this:

```
<img className="..." src={imageFile}></img>
```

I want to use base64 encoded images, I think I can do this:

```
<img className="..." src={"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaH...."}></img>
```

the problem is that the base64 strings are huge, and for some reason I cant store them in my component.
I tried putting them in a txt file and doing:

```
fs.readFile('image.txt', function(err, data){console.log(data);})
```

but I get tons of errors, including:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
```

among others.

any ideas how to store base64 strings in a separate file and load them into my component?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not read any files in react using fs module, there is one way to do that but its bit debatable

Comment: do you know a way to store base64 strings in a separate file and then import them?

Comment: This is a very strange way to go about showing images, why not host them on your app server and have a url link to them?

Comment: true, I'm trying to deploy to Arweave, and this (I think) the easiest way to include images

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to store `base64` data and export it.

```
// filename.js
const image = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaH....";

export default image;

// import
import image from 'filename';
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the base64 using Buffer

```
let [imgSrc,setImgSrc] = useState('')
// 
let base64_to_imgsrc = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64").toString()
//add the string to the state
setImgSrc(base64_to_imgsrc)
```

and use it like this

```
  <img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgSrc} />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, my main problem is storing the base64 strings. is there a way to import the strings from a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

There is three-way to do that, with `FileReader` and with `fetch` and the simplest way is to import it.

**With Import**

```
import Base64JSON from "./readme.json";

console.log(Base64JSON);
```

**With FileReader**

```js
const readFile = async (json) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)]);

    reader.onload = async (e) => resolve(JSON.parse(e.target.result));
    reader.readAsText(blob);
  });
```

**With Fetch**

```js
const readFileUsingHttp = async (path) => {
  const json = await fetch(path);
  return json.json();
};
```

Here is the sandbox URL that shows all techniques.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-golick-uvtcnh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this is the solution! thank you, I didnt even need to use fetch or Filereader, I just had to put it in a json file and import it!

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!